# What is the closest to Dart's List.asMap().forEach() returning a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

In one screen (a `StatelessWidget`) we display a list of words. One
word can be edited in the second screen (a `StatefulWidget`) through a
`TextField`.

[image: two screens]

We return the modified word through
`Navigator.pop`, but the assignment marked "ineffectual" is just
that. Using `words.map` creates an entirely new list, and although it
*is* a closure, lacking an index into `words` we are unable to store
back the modified word.

Using `List.asMap()` would solve this, by sending over the index, but
`List.asMap().forEach()` will not return a list that we can use for
the children of the `Column`.

What is the closest to Dart's List.asMap().forEach() returning a list?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: WordsWidget(
        words: ["apples", "oranges"])));
}

class EditWordWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String word;
  EditWordWidget({super.key, required this.word});

  @override
  State<EditWordWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<EditWordWidget> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.word);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Edit Word')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [Text('Word: '),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  onSubmitted: (String value) {
                    widget.word = value;
                  },
              )),
          ]),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, widget.word);
            },
            child: const Text('Done'),
          )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WordsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> words;

  WordsWidget({Key? key, required this.words}) : super(key: key) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Words')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: words.map((word) =>
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('${word}   '),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final new_word = await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                        (context) => EditWordWidget(word: word)),
                    );
                    word = new_word; // ineffectual
                  },
                  child: const Text('Edit'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: review the protocol of Map, and you'll see aMap.entries.map, or aMap.map as possibilities that emit either a new map or a new list, as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this.  If you want an index into a `List`, just iterate with indices.

```dart
          children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1)
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('${words[i]}   '),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // ...
                      words[i] = new_word;
                    },
                    child: const Text('Edit'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ],
```

Dart 3.0 adds an [`indexed`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/IterableExtensions/indexed.html) extension that would allow you to do:

```dart
children: [
  for (var (i, word) in words.indexed)
    Row(...),
],
```

For Dart 2, [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides a [`mapIndexed`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html) extension method:

```dart
children: words.mapIndexed((i, word) => Row(...)).toList(),
```

Note that although the above approaches would mutate the `words` `List`, they won't have any visible effect in your Flutter application since `WordsWidget` is a `StatelessWidget`.  To properly rebuild its widget tree, you additionally should change it to be a `StatefulWidget` and move the `words[i] = new_word;` mutation into a `setState` callback.